# Apache/PHP not attempting to make external MySQL connections

Tags: php, mysql, remote-connections

So I'm doing some testing at the moment but it seems PHP/Apache is not even attempting to make an external MySQL connection.

I've confirmed that there is MySQL connectivity between the two servers and in doing this have  confirmed that MySQL is running, listening on internal port, has permissions to login from the web server, etc etc.

The problem is Joomla and other PHP scripts cannot make a connection and via TCPDump appear not to be even trying to make a connection to any external hosts.  I've tested this on trying to connect to a dedicated server as well besides the cloud environment.

Besides doing this with Joomla I've also tested it with Wordpress as well as just a typical PHP MySQL connection with no CMS engines (single file to test connection) which all fails.

I've recorded a video for anyone to actually see the issue in action.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwC2sNaSvvU

---

You can see in the video me using the web server at command line connecting using "# mysql -h

Then, via the actual web server the PHP files do not initiate a database connection and apparently don't even try.

All firewalls are disabled and turned off and are currently wide open for the trouble shooting purpose but it still fails.

---

I am not sure if I missed something but this is a normal set up and for some reason seems to be acting quirky.

### ----

---

> ANSWER: SELINUX Is blocking the out-going connection.  Either disable SELinux or enable the remote connection through SELinux

Comment: Did you install mysql/mysqli support (module)? Is it activated in php.ini?

Comment: check your web server logs. looks like the php-mysqli module is not installed/configured `yum install php-mysqli`. People at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) may be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running Linux and SELinux is enabled (CentOS, Fedora, RHEL enables it y default) have a look on:

https://serverfault.com/questions/240015/how-do-i-allow-mysql-connections-through-selinux

Comment: Ah thank you so much.  Can't believe I over looked that haha.  Issue resolved at last! :D

Comment: That was my case also when I converted to Fedora